# Implement pattern lock in windows phone or simple password authentication

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, pattern-matching, password-protection

I am building a application like photo lock. I want to implement Pattern lock to that application i founded the one code for that but i can't understand can anyone help??? here's link for code which is founded [It's a link to pattern lock code](http://nishantcop.blogspot.in/2014/02/pattern-lock-for-windows-phone.html)   And also want to know simple saving password validate that password and change that password. I am a new to development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isolated storage application settings`, which are per-application settings Variable. Their scope is determined by the full path of the application .xap file. For example, you can store application settings, such as number of images to display per page, page layout customization settings, and so on.

You can store n Access user password in it and check it thorugh-out the Application

More Refrence you can find here "[How to: Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx)"